# Disable Sticky Header Just on Mobile

Tags: header, navigation, sticky

I'm looking to disable my sticky header just on mobile devices, I've found a couple of threads but still haven't been able to get around this as I either end up disabling the header entirely or doing nothing at all.

This is the site: http://dancefloordjs.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

[Media queries are your friend](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). You're using bootstrap, so your first breakpoint is at 768 pixels. Put your styles for the non-sticky, mobile header outside of any media query in your custom.css (or whatever the name of the css file is that you're overriding default Bootstrap styles with) since Bootstrap is a mobile-first framework. Then, inside of a block like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
   //your custom styles
}
```

drop in the styles for your sticky header. You can read more about customizing Bootstrap [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/12/customizing-bootstrap/), including alternative and advances techniques other than a custom.css file.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I'm pretty confident that I have the media queries down as I've used these with previous tasks on this site.

I'm having trouble taking the sticky nav away regardless of device type, any advice on what I should change?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed using:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {.float-right {float: none; width: 100%;}}
```